# why do I get 404 error or a weird url while linking two pages in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, view, hyperlink, controller

I am trying to link two pages (the homepage and the about page ) in codeigniter. But when I click on the about page link

```
<a href="aboutpage">Click here for the About page</a>
```

a 404 error is displayed

when I changed the link to

```
<a href="site/aboutpage">Click here for the About page</a>
```

site being the controller - a weird url is generated when I click on the homepage link in the about page

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/site/site/site/site/site/homepage
```

A site is added every time I click in the homepage link or the about page link

Following is my **controller site.php** :-

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Site extends CI_Controller 
{

```
public function index()
{
    $this->homepage();
}

public function homepage()
{
    $this->load->view('view_home');
}

public function aboutpage()
{
    $this->load->view('view_about');
}
```

}

This is my **view_home.php**

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to homepage</h1>

<div id="body">

    <p>This is Homepage</p>
    <br />

    <a href="aboutpage">Click here for the About page</a>
</div>

<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
```

this is my **view_about.php**

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to About Page</h1>

<div id="body">

    <p>This is About Page</p>
    <br />

    <a href="homepage">Click here for the Homepage</a>
</div>

<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
```

I even tried to see if there is a problem with my .htaccess file. But everything seems to be fine

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This isn't a Codeigniter problem as such. You just need to add a slash to the front of your urls. I.E.  `href="/site/aboutpage"` . Adding a forward slash to the start of the link makes the link relative to your homepage, and is the equivelent of `http://yoursite.com/site/aboutpage`. Without the slash the links are opened relative to the current page, hence why they continue to be added to the url add infinitum.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>site/aboutpage" id="lnk_aboutus">About&nbsp;Us</a>
```

start using base_url to make sure that url's formed are good.

and make sure you set your base_url in application/config/config.php like this

```
  $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/mysitename/";
```

Comment: hi, I tried making this change <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>site/aboutpage" id="lnk_aboutus">About&nbsp;Us</a>. But now the link does not appear. Then I tried <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/site/aboutpage" id="lnk_aboutus">About&nbsp;Us</a> and it worked fine

Comment: is this method also the right way to do it? this method seems to work even without making a change to the config file

Comment: @Stacy J - No this is not the right way to do it. You should leave your config as it is and instead use the  `site_url()` function when you need to echo the websites url.

Comment: @Stacy have you added url helper in the controller?If not add $this->load->helper('url'); to your controller or autoload it in config/autoload.php   $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Comment: Note, `site_url()` is the function provided for this. E.g. to link to `domain.com/foo/bar`, you would just use `<?php echo site_url('foo/bar');?>` - and the base URL will be used.